# How To Pass Clicked List Item Value to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I'm making a SMS app, I have a contact list, I want to be able to tap on contact and pass that contact number into new activity so that I could send message to that contact number,
I know How can we pass Value of clicked List item to new Activity, but somehow I'm not able to use that Intent.putExtra method in my scenario.

```java
private void getContactList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
                        id
                    },
                    null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your given code reads from the database, where is the list item click code as per your question heading.

Comment: @rahat I'm at work at this moment and don't have that code with me
But so far I'm able to go to new activity when I tap on any contact,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) to do this. You mentioned that you somehow couldn't call `putExtra` on your intent, make sure it isn't a typo as it is supposed to be `putExtras`, also make sure you are creating your intent correctly as shown below.

In the activity that will send the data:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("phoneNo", phoneNo);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then on the receiving activity:

```java
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String number = bundle.getString("phoneNo");
```

Comment: When I'm trying to use your code, I'm getting error on "phoneNo" because it's not valid outside of try{ }

Comment: You can put the code inside your `try{}`, what is needing the `try{}` block?

Comment: Not try { }, I'm sorry, my bad, I was trying to say that "phoneNo" is only valid in getContacts() method, How do I use it outside? Can you please make a complete code based on my code?

Comment: Well once you have the phone number you can just implement the code above to add the phone number into the bundle and then use the second code block code to receive it in the second activity

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Thanks man, You Code helped, I just had to make some changes on my own code but.